# harmonic coordinates on non-compact manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, manifolds, harmonic-functions

Is it possible to show the existence of harmonic coordinates (e.g., on uniform-sized balls) on certain classes of non-compact Riemannian manifolds? For example, one may expect that such harmonic coordinates exist on a manifold that has doubling volume measure and supports Poincare inequality?

Comment: A key word is harmonic radius, see these notes http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/ricerca/rendiconti/ARCHIVIO/1997(4)/569-605.pdf

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I want to ask the following: can we get a uniform lower bound on the harmonic radius, provided that the non-compact manifold has doubling volume measure and supports Poincare inequality?

Comment: Thank you Andy!  I think the corollary on p.577 or Hebey--Herzlich answers my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Main Lemma 2.2 in "Michael T. Anderson, Convergence and rigidity of manifolds under Ricci curvature bounds" (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01233434) says essentially that there is a uniform lower bound for the harmonic radius in term of Ricci curvature bound and lower bound of injectivity radius.

The paper "E. HEBEY & M. HERZLICH, Harmonic coordinates, harmonic radius and convergence of Riemannian manifolds" (http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/ricerca/rendiconti/ARCHIVIO/1997(4)/569-605.pdf) is an exposition of the above paper of Anderson, which is, in my viewpoint, easier to read.

Comment: Thank you very much Truong! I think the corollary on p.577 or Hebey--Herzlich answers my question.